# Where m_pMainWnd is instantiated

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i am just starting out in microsoft foundation classes, and in my hello world application using the new project wizard, i see a reference to m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) and m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow() in the InitInstance() method. i understand m_pMainWnd is a pointer to the main application window. my problem is that i only see its declaration in afxwin.h but not its instantiation anywhere. Is there something i am missing, and please just correct me if i am wrong. i am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main frame window is instantiated in InitInstance() method of your application (CWinApp-derived) class just like that:

```
CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CNetworkManagerDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CNetworkManagerView));
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

Comment: so the included macro call RUNTIME_CLASS(CNetworkManagerView) will instantiate m_pMainWnd with a reference to the CNetworkManagerView class?

Comment: The RUNTIME_CLASS macro is used to call
CRuntimeClass::CreateObject() to instantiate the object. Tricky.

After the doc, frame and view are created in this manner they are
initialized by the framework.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for your help. I have not been able to proceed with my studies since yesterday just because of this.